Объясните, пожалуйста, принцип работы VPN
Я начинающий в области сетевого программирования и хотел бы узнать, как работает VPN. Буду благодарен, если вы сможете объяснить принцип его работы максимально подробно, особенно клиентскую часть.

В системе создаётся виртуальный сетевой интерфейс, весь трафик которого направляется в программу, а дальше эта программа делает с трафиком что хочет, например передаёт кому-нибудь через интернет, вот и всё в принципе

@andreymal как я понял, делается виртуальный интрефейс с помощью tun/tap драйвера?

Типа того, но конкретная реализация зависит от операционной системы

@andreymal вы случайно не знаете команды как как весь трафик перенаправить на виртуальный интерфейс в ubuntu?

В линуксе это вроде как-то связано с ioctl TUNSETIFF, но подробностей не знаю

@andreymal спасибо!

Хотя стоп, конкретно касательно «весь трафик перенаправить» это делается через настройки таблицы маршрутизации, изменением маршрута по умолчанию на ip-адрес назначенный нужному интерфейсу, примерно как-то так https://superuser.com/questions/1814912 (и, строго говоря, прямого отношения к vpn уже не имеет)

@andreymal, насколько я понимаю, при создании туннеля (в виртуальном сетевом интерфейсе tun например) можно указать конкретный IP-адрес сокета на том же компьютере где размещается этот виртуальный интрефейс и туда и будет поступать все пакеты?
